# How to import multiple sheets in an Excel Workbook

Tags: r, import, apply

I would like to import eight sheets from an Excel file and save them as separate objects. For the purposes of this post lets call the excel file Test.xlsx and the sheets Q1, HH5, L9, P9, TOO4, GG1, JQ1, HJ0, BM6, VT8.  Note, all the sheets have a different naming convention.

I am very used to SAS where you can build a macro and dynamically change the variable to cycle through the sheet names.  How should I go about this in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here every sheet is saved as a data.frame (and hence as a separate object):

```
sheet_names <-c("Q1", "HH5", "L9", "P9", "TOO4", "GG1", "JQ1", "HJ0", "BM6", "VT8")
for (i in 1:(length(sheet_names))) {
      excel_sheet <- read_excel("Test.xlsx", sheet = paste0(sheet_names[i]))
      assign(paste0(sheet_names[i]), excel_sheet)
      rm(excel_sheet)
    }
```

Let met know if it helped.

Comment: I return an error: Error in assign(paste0(sheet_names[i], excel_sheet)) : 
  argument "value" is missing, with no default. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: I updated the awnser. One bracket was false. Now it is correct: `assign(paste0(sheet_names[i]), excel_sheet)`

Comment: Nice to hear. Can you accept the awnser so others see that it worked? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
library("readxl")
library("openxlsx")

setwd("C:\\...")

filenames <- list.files()

data <- list()

for(i in 1:length(filenames)){

    data[[i]] <- read.xlsx(filenames[i])

}
```

This should solve your problem. In filenames function you can use `recursive = T` to open files inside the folders on te directory and/or `pattern = ".xlsx"` to find only the .xlsx files on directory.